# How locally managing component's state in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working in react and i use redux. I'm a little bit confused. For example, I have two buttons and each time i click on of of them i want it color change.

It work's great but the problem is : both button have their color changed when i click on one of them.

I don't know how to tell to react/redux to only consider the button clicked just before.

Any idea about how to solve this ?

thanks.

Comment: Show us some code. What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that's not the way how to ask a good question. You need to show us some code, what did you try, where is the problem.

[Check here how to ask good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

The solution for your problem would be to store the index of the clicked button in your local state and then check inside rendering your buttons if the index is the same as the index in the state.

You can do something like this :

```
let buttons = ['Button 1', 'Button 2', "Button 3"]


class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
        active: null
    }
  }

  handleClick(i,event){
    this.setState({
        active: i
    })
  }

   render(){
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.buttons.map((button, i) => {
               return (
                  <div key={i}><button className={this.state.active === i ? 'active' : ''} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, i)}>{button}</button></div>
               );
            })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

React.render(<Test buttons={buttons}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1515/).

Comment: Thanks. You solved my issue.  I tought react was able to handle each single component's state separately. I was expecting something like a magic prop or option, but now i figured out it should be done manually. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to start playing with React and no Redux for now. There are great courses https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux you can watch.

The answer for your question is - you are using one variable for checking both buttons states.